# Need xml data to keep POST-ing every 2 seconds until a response is received

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

This is a very small application for a prototype/experiment. A device is going into sleep every so often to save battery life and a user will access a local webpage and press a button to change something with the device--this sends a POST to the device using the javascript code below.

Since the device can be sleeping when the user presses a button it will miss the POST. I know this is bad practice but I basically need the webpage to keep POST-ing (don't even know if I'm using the terminology correctly) or sending data until it receives the response. I tried a while loop but it only sent it once, maybe I put it in the wrong place.

```
function execPOST(url, postData, callback) {
    var postRequest = newAjaxRequest();
    postRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (postRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (postRequest.error) {
                callback(1, "Request had an error.");
                alert('postRequest Error');
            } else {
                var status;
                try {
                    status = postRequest.status;
                } catch (err) {
                    callback(1, "Failed to get HTTP status from server.");
                    return;
                }
                if (status == 200 || status == 0) {
                    callback(0, postRequest.responseText);
                } else {
                    callback(1, "POST: Unexpected HTTP Status: "
                            + postRequest.status);
                    alert('POST: Unexpected HTTP Status: '
                        + postRequest.status);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (postRequest.overrideMimeType){
        postRequest.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
    }
    postRequest.open("POST", url, false);
 //I tried adding this while loop hoping it would keep sending but it only sent once
    while (postRequest.readystate != 4)
    {
        setTimeout('',2000);
        postRequest.send(postData);
    }
    return postRequest;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send multiple requests, or to continue waiting for a response to a single request indefinitely?

Comment: I need it to continue sending requests indefinitely until it gets a response. This won't cause any problems since this is the only thing that needs to happen on this web page.


Is there a reason why I won't be able to do it within the function I provided? I'm new to javascript and I'm having trouble finding what I need after looking at socket.io information also I don't even jquery

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at [socket.io](http://socket.io) to "ping" the device in a loop until it wakes up, THEN send the POST request.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work since the ip I would need to ping could change, it's also the ip that is hosting the web page. Also I couldn't find enough detailed information using socket.io to ping

Answer (score 0):

have you considered to use jquery?

```
function ping () {
    $.ajax (
          <url>
        , {
              error:    function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                        }
            , timeout:  5000    // in ms
            , type:     'POST'
          }
    }).done(function ( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        // whatever
    }).fail(function ( jqxhr, textStatus, data ) {
        // note that the order of arguments is different from that of the success handler ('done') !
        if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
            ping();
        }
        else {
            // ... more error handling
        }
    });
```

for more info, [consult the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).