# How to keep sending ajax requests until a response is received?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I need to keep hammering the same ajax request every 2 seconds or so until a response is received. This is because the device it is being sent to goes to sleep for 3 seconds at a time--it needs to catch the request when it's awake. Is there a simple way to do this by adding something to my code? Without using jquery...

This what I have for only sending one request:

```
 function ePOST(url, postData, callback) {
var postReq = AjaxRequest();
postReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (postReq.readyState == 4) {
        if (postReq.error) {
            callback(1, "Request had an error.");
            alert('postReq Error');
        } else {
            var stat;
            try {
                stat = postReq.status;
            } catch (err) {
                callback(1, "Failed to get HTTP status from server.");
                return;
            }
            if (stat == 200 || stat == 0) {
                callback(0, postReq.responseText);
            } else {
                callback(1, "Unexpected HTTP Status: "
                        + postReq.status);
                alert('Unexpected HTTP Status: '
                    + postReq.status);
            }
        }
    }
}
if (postReq.overrideMimeType){
    postReq.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
}
setTimeout('',1000);
postReq.open("POST", url, true);
postReq.send(postData);
return postReq;
}
```

Comment: possible (read: probable) duplicate of '[Need xml data to keep POST-ing every 2 seconds until a response is received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133892/need-xml-data-to-keep-post-ing-every-2-seconds-until-a-response-is-received)' ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with very little modification to that function.

```
var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
    epost(<url>,<data>,function(error,response) {
        if (!error) {
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
        } else {
            alert(response); // or handle error some other way
        }
        // do something with the data
    });
},2000);
```

I'm not 100% sure that intervalId will be available to the closure but if not you can always make it like this:

```
var intervalId;
intervalId = window.setInterval(....
```

The only issue I can think of is if the ajax call takes longer then 2 seconds to return, in which case you may not clear the interval in time.